# New Extensions not going in Community Folder?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, extensions

I have recently moved a complete Magento installation to a new server. While I was debugging some issues, I noticed the community extensions were not listed in the MagentoConnect Manager.

When I went to install a new extension, its code files were not added to the `app/code/community` folder, but it did install successfully, but I have no idea where it put the code files!

Any thoughts as to what could be going on here?

Comment: Did you look in app/code/local? What extension was it? How did you install it?

Comment: Yeah looks like it was installed to `app/code/local`. Its strange because I'm installing with the Magento Connect Manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to take a look at the bootstrap file of the extension you installed. It is located in `app/etc/modules/` dir. There is a `<codePool>` node which defines either the extension will live in `app/code/local` or `app/code/community`.

In order to have the list of installed extensions in MagnetoConnect you have to keep the contents of `var/package` dir.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary that if you are installing an extension via Connect Manager then it should install in community folder, this directory either community or local totally depends on the extension owner or creator who packages the extension, at the time of packaging the extension creator mentions in which directory(community or local) extension should install. 
The main point is install directory and codePool node in extension registration xml file should be same.

Comment: I see. And do extensions get registered in the database somewhere when they are installed? The Extensions I had installed previous to the move are not showing up in the Connect Manager.

Comment: No, in native magento or you can say by default there is no such thing that extensions are listed somewhere in database. Modules installed via Connect Manager can only be seen in Connect Manager not all extensions. You can see all your installed extension only in app/etc/modules directory.

Answer (score 1):

check **app/code/local** folder, maybe extension installed in local